# openGL a game design way for osx

Tags: ios, macos, opengl

My target is a game, which will be working on MacOS and iOS later as well.

A first way are using GLUT inside main loop:

```
int main ( int argc, char * argv [] )
{
                                // initialize glut
    glutInit            ( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode ( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH );
    glutInitWindowSize  ( 500, 500 );


                                // create window
    glutCreateWindow ( "Simple GLUT Example" );

                                // register handlers
    glutDisplayFunc  ( display );
    glutReshapeFunc  ( reshape );
    glutKeyboardFunc ( key     );
    glutMouseFunc    ( mouse   );
    glutMotionFunc   ( motion  );
    glutIdleFunc     ( animate );

    glutMainLoop ();

    return 0;
}
```

That is may be fine decision, but i have no experience for now, how i can catch user interactions (touches, mouse moving e.t.c.)

Second way, which i'm investigate is using a subclass of NSOpenGLView:

```
    - (void) setupRenderTimer
    {
        NSTimeInterval timeInterval = 0.005;

        renderTimer =  [ NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeInterval
                                                          target:self
                                                        selector:@selector( updateGLView: )
                                                        userInfo:nil repeats:YES ];
        [ [ NSRunLoop currentRunLoop ] addTimer:renderTimer
                                        forMode:NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode ];
        [ [ NSRunLoop currentRunLoop ] addTimer:renderTimer
                                        forMode:NSModalPanelRunLoopMode ];
    }


    /*
     * Called by the rendering timer.
     */
    - (void) updateGLView:(NSTimer *)timer
    {
        if( glView != nil )
            [ glView drawRect:[ glView frame ] ];
    }

- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    [ NSApp setDelegate:self ];   // We want delegate notifications
    renderTimer = nil;
    //[self makeFirstResponder:self ];
    glView = [ [ MyOpenGLView alloc ] initWithFrame:[ self.myGLview frame ]
                                          colorBits:16 depthBits:16 fullscreen:FALSE ];
    if( glView != nil )
    {
        [ self.window.contentView addSubview:glView ];
        [ self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self ];
        [ self setupRenderTimer ];
    }
    else
        [ self createFailed ];
}
```

Finally I like to keep advantages of Cocoa IB (build in IB all controls and keep it upfront OpenGL context). In case of that i was not find until now a solution, which working fine under MacOS, where i can using cocoa IB elements upfront OpenGL context. In IB context always upfront all elements, hack with:

```
const GLint aValue = 1;
[[self openGLContext] setValues:&aValue
                   forParameter:NSOpenGLCPSurfaceOpacity];
```

gives me good result setting background color to back :

```
glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );   // Black background
```

doesn't work:

[image]

What i like to ask for:
- do any way to be success in second way (performance reasons may be critical for me in future, a game will have big 3d world). If yes, can you please share for some useful example or write a fix of my current bug.

- if a first way only one way, what i a good code organization to support in one code both platforms iOS and osx (write some code samples too). is GLUT will work fine to control touches for iOS, is too hard to replace all cocoa-touch features like long press e.t.c
- i know well, what i will need to do a platform specific changes, but maybe u can share some experience, how it can be done better and easiest.

P.S. i understand that i can using GLKit, but unfortunately now it work very bad for MacOS, have known bugs.

Comment: You might have more luck on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/, however your question is fairly broad in scope, you're going to need to narrow it down to something a bit more concise.

Comment: thx fro suggestion, can i keep a same details. I guess some users can answer only to one part of question, and i will approve answer only to that part.

Comment: If you want ask multiple questions, separate them into shorter separate self-contained questions. See: http://sscce.org/

Comment: "*A first way are using GLUT inside main loop:*" If you're making a game, you should not be using GLUT.

Comment: @NicolBolas what i have to using for? I'm using currently using examples from book

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to take the time to do it right, I will suggest reading a book or two, and also the tutorials will help. Here are two tutorials on the very basics: [NeHe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/), [GameTutorials](http://www.gametutorials.com/gtstore/c-1-test-cat.aspx).

Also, here is a very good beginners book (it is free): [Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/).

On a side note, GLUT is not the best way to go for game programming. Seriously, read. Example OpenGL scripts will use GLUT for the sake of simplicity and compactness, but it is not the way to do it in real world.